# What does Teams getting its own domain mean practically?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

[image: Screenshot of notification - Says "Stack Overflow for Teams is moving to its own domain! When the migration is complete, you will access your Teams at stackoverflowteams.com, and they will no longer appear in the left sidebar for stackoverflow.com]

I got a toast saying -  "Stack Overflow for Teams is moving to its own domain! When the migration is complete, you will access your Teams at *stackoverflowteams.com*, and they will no longer appear in the left sidebar for *stackoverflow.com* on my left sidebar.

What does this mean for the close integration between Stack Overflow's public instance and teams, and how will accounts be managed going forward?

Comment: Related Teams Help article: [Teams Domain Migration: User Guide](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/6649858-teams-domain-migration-user-guide)

Comment: You'll have to log in separately unless you use a browser that's some years old in which case take care not to surf the internet with it.

Comment: does this mean we'll finally be free of the teams navbar?

Comment: I don't know - I do feel like if they're moving private Q&A out, its a great time to move meta and chat into the side bar :D

Comment: I'm sure it's just gonna have collectives moved in

Comment: Will links within the specific team's instance be updated automatically?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm updated the answer to include this—all links to your Teams instance will be redirected to your new Teams site.

Comment: Related: [Why is the removal of Teams from stackoverflow.com necessitating the removal of all ties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421496/1478931)

Comment: And related on MSE: [Is Stack Overflow for Teams going to be removed from the sidebar on the rest of the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383092/335251)

Answer (score 13):

The Stack Overflow for Teams site (moving to stackoverflowteams.com) will be decoupled from the global, public community at stackoverflow.com. This has two main benefits:

1. Provides you with better visibility into whether you are working
   within your private Team or in the global, public community.
2. Helps Stack Overflow better service, test, and improve Teams without
   making infrastructure changes to our public site and vice versa.

For users of both the public community and private Teams, you will have to log into each instance. After your private Team is migrated to the new domain, it will no longer appear in the left sidebar of stackoverflow.com. That's why we're asking users to bookmark their new Teams sites (stackoverflowteams.com/c/*[your-team]*) so they can easily access Teams after the migration, separate from the public site at stackoverflow.com. We know this is different from the experience you're used to, but the aim is to help all users work confidently in their private Teams without concern of accidentally posting anywhere outside of your organization. You will still be able to use your personal stackoverflow.com account to engage with the global community outside of your private Teams.

With Unified Search, you will still be able to access the public community's wealth of knowledge from your private Teams by opting to include read-only results from stackoverflow.com in your search.

All links to your Teams site will be redirected to your new Teams site. If you link to the public site from your private Team, these links will still go to the public site.

[Read the article from the Teams Help Center](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/6649858-teams-domain-migration-user-guide) for more info.

Comment: A specific concern here - especially from the moderator community is they didn't want a stack overflow account (for privacy and other considerations). Would one be able to use teams *without* a SO account?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I hope I understand your question, but I may need to gather more info to get you an answer. Are you asking if you will need a public Stack Overflow account to access Teams?

Comment: Yup - a network account is 'fine' but generally mods can see PII and some folks prefer to limit their exposure, so they'd prefer not to have an SO account as a prerequisite to the site.

Comment: got it. nothing should change about your current Teams account, and you won't be required to create a new public account to maintain your Teams account. I'll gather some more info to update our documentation so this is stated clearly in our comms. thanks for your questions.

Comment: Hm. More precisely - will I need an SO account for a new teams account?

Comment: Being able to have Teams displayed in the left-nav was presented as *the primary reason for the left-nav's existence*. It seems counterproductive to remove Teams from the left-nav and retain the left-nav. Given that you're removing Teams from the left-nav, are you going to remove the soon-to-be *very* sparse left-nav?

Comment: @youreawizardcarrie There seems to be a miscommunication as to what Journeyman Geek is asking. Journeyman Geek is pointing out that, currently, in order to have a Teams account, the user **must** have an account on Stack Overflow main. Having an account on SO main is seen as unacceptable to a substantial number of people (including a notable number who are moderators on non-SO sites in the SE Network). What is being asked is: will these changes mean that it is no longer *necessary* to have an account on the main Stack Overflow site in order to have a Teams account?

Comment: I can confirm that users won't need a Stack Overflow account to use Teams that are hosted in stackoverflowteams.com

Comment: Will there be a transition period during which both domains will work?

Comment: @MadScientist We have redirects in place for all links on stackoverflow.com/c/<your-team>. We do encourage you to update your bookmarks but both the old and the new domain will keep working.

Comment: Do we still get inbox notifications on the main site for things which happened in Teams?

Comment: @tripleee, no it looks like the plan is to completely separate Teams from SO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383875/282094