# Are there any issues using a single account for a subset of Stack Overflow for Teams users?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm considering Stack Overflow for Teams, but we have computer stations that are not dedicated to a single staff member. When staff need a computer, they go to the nearest terminal or grab the closest computer cart (mobile A/V style cart with a laptop).

In this environment, are there any issues I might encounter?

Can you have a SOfT account without any connection to any other Stack Exchange accounts?

We currently use a Wiki for this function, but the Q&A format is better suited for us than a Wiki.

Comment: Do people using these carts also share the same email account or something?

Comment: For Stack Overflow itself an account must represent an individual not a group of them. Authentication to teams (at least for the free version) requires a Stack Overflow Account, so if you have multiple people using that account it would technically break the terms. I don't know if, in practice, penalties would ever be applied if they never interact with the main site itself, however, I could see that Stack Overflow may well might, as you could then apply for a version of the software for a number of users lower than the actual number you require.

Comment: "*Can you have a SOfT account without any connection to any other stackexchange accounts?*" perhaps after [domain migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420980/what-does-teams-getting-its-own-domain-mean-practically#comment930788_420984) is done: "*I can confirm that users won't need a Stack Overflow account to use Teams that are hosted in stackoverflowteams.com*"

Comment: They don't log in as themselves and load their own profile on these shared machines? How do you figure out which staff member used a machine to upload malware to servers or download pirated software? Seems like it should be trivial to have them each auth to a service independently.

Comment: @Makoto yes, they would normally all share a read only account for information they need.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Unlikely as the computers are just kiosk style with no login, no write access, no network shares, and no command prompts. But your point is well taken. The reason we don't have them log in is two fold: **Time to login, get answer, log out** is too long and **Too high a chance in the rush someone will forget to log out**.

Comment: I feel like it would also be very confusing if {generic login} asked a question and then two other {generic logins} posted contradictory answers or comments and then two other {generic logins} got in an argument.

Comment: The current plan is only Admins will be empowered (in policy) to answer or even ask questions (with self answers). The {generic user} will be using it as a tool to look up policy for how they should handle an issue. We are not yet using Teams but I envision questions like:  **How do I handle an ordered item that we are out of stock currently?** **If the customer sent a message they wish to cancel the order, how do I accept that?"**

Comment: @JamesRisner: That's a **big yikes.**  It might be more prudent to set a default incognito mode session for the browser so that when the browser is closed, the sessions are all destroyed instead of sharing a single account like it's 2004.  Most joking aside though, I could see some challenges in a site like Teams supporting such a workflow since the [ToS does stipulate 1 person === 1 account](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#obligations).  But I dunno.

Comment: @Makoto I had forgotten the ToS, probably because I was going to include these users and add an additional for the {generic login} in my user count. Maybe I need to dream up a way to get them a way to login in without passwords quickly (no idea how to do that) and auto log them out in 30 or 60 seconds of idle (also no idea how to do that.)

Comment: @JamesRisner:  ...no.  Just a session with an incognito window.  If one wants to log back in, then they can use their own credentials after they close the browser.  Beyond the sentiment of folks managing their own account, there would be no impetus to put super-duper extra safety rail padding around all of this.  Unless what you're looking at is connected to a financial institution, session timeouts are more of a pain than they're worth.